# Does absence of a reference count as "general reference"?

Tags: discussion, general-reference

An interesting conundrum with a recent question: [Which Doctor Who episodes were written by Steve Cole?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24415/which-doctor-who-episodes-were-written-by-steve-cole)

A few people have voted to close it as general reference, but someone points out that the linked WP *doesn't* say he wrote any particular episodes.

Then again - there is no evidence on IMDB of Cole's involvement in the TV series.

So - does lack of reference count as general reference? How much lack?

Comment: Ironically, I was actually asking in that comment but 5 other people decided to take it as a rhetorical question and VTCed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a case of an absence of a reference. The reference (the Wikipedia article exists). And the reference (as do other sources) does provide the answer.

While the Wikipedia article doesn't explicitly say anything about his writing *Doctor Who* episodes, it would be highly surprising if it omitted that fact, since both his writing and his involvement in *Doctor Who* are central topics of the article. IMDB doesn't mention his writing any episode either, and it's supposed to be complete. So yes, this is a general reference question; IMDB answers it authoritatively, and Wikipedia answers it with a high presumption of correctness. A high presumption of correctness is sufficient to close the question anyway — general references can be wrong now and then, but the question should provide some justification for doubting it.

Steve Cole's own website is yet another confirmation that he did not write any episode. That's yet another confirmation.

The information is far easier to find elsewhere on the Internet than on Stack Exchange. That's the point of the general reference close reason. Yes, this is a general reference question.

Answer (score 2):

There's no lack of reference here.  The "general reference" in this case is actually the website cited in the question itself.  The question spawns from a misunderstanding of the author's works summary on his "About" page.  The page never says the author wrote any episodes - in fact, it specifically says that his work in the Doctor Who universe is in the form of books.

Comment: Sounds like a case of 'too localized' in addition to 'general reference'.

Comment: @Keen The only "too localized" I can think of which would apply here, is time.  Sure, there is the possibility that this author might at some point be invited to write an episode.  However, I'm not quite sure I'd use the fact that this author is still alive as a reason to close.

Comment: 'Too localized' as in most people will read that linked page and read the bit that he's only written books.